# ASP.NET master page - reload-flickering problem in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, master-pages

Is there a possibility/trick (besides the usage of the AJAX update panel) to prevent the **ASP.NET master page reload flickering effect** in IE) every time the user makes a postback?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this trick will help you (for IE)

http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/01/31/stop-ie-flickering-between-pages.aspx

http://nishantpant.wordpress.com/2006/11/02/fake-ajax-fajax-use-this-for-a-cool-tranisition-effect/

http://www.codesack.com/aspnet/removing-flickering-and-postback-in-master-page-fajax/

Comment: This is exactly that what I need. In Firefox there is no flickering. But I need it for an intranet applications. In our company the IE is the standard browser. Thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Without the UpdatePanel (or some other AJAX magic) the entire page is reloaded from the server every postback. Hence the flicker.